# error code 0xc0000139 Qt debug

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, qt-creator, mingw32

I wrote a Qt application originally with Qt libs 4.8.1. Now I am ona different PC. I installed Qt 5.2.1 with Qt Creator and then the Qt 4.8.6 libs. I specified the right kit with compiler (MinGW47_32) and the right gdb. Now when I compile it it builds and then tells me Programm crashed. If i try debugging i get the Message : "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139." I googled the error code and Qt version 5.0.1 has a recorded bug though I used 4.8.6 i looked at it and it was about a secong MinGW compiler installed. I got a second one too so I uninstalled Qt removed the compiler (deleted it since i never "installed" it just copied the files) the I reinstalled Qt but still have the same problem Google doesnt say andthing else about that code so I wonder what the problem is ???
hope I wrote down all necessary infos if somethings missing just ask :D
thanks

ps. this only happens with the 4.8.6 libs the 5.2.1 are working fine

Comment: Try checking "Clear system environment" in project's Build Environment section. As I understand it - whatever you choose as compiler/qt pair - it gets polluted by PATH variable on launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I made it work guess its no real fix but a workaround.
In Qt Creator use the system environment but set the path to your compiler libs and bin directory and to your Qt bin and libs directory. For run also use the system environment.
Then build the app in debug mode. Then go and copy all *.dll that you need for your application into the directory you built the app with (something like build-debug/debug).
Watch out for the Qt libs there are normal libs and debug ones the debug ones have a "d" at the end of there names (e.g. QtCore**d**.dll) and you need those. If you aren't sure which ones you need open the .exe file you just built with the dependencyWalker. Now you should be able to run it through QtCreator.